# Отличие 0 or NULL? Что лучше использовать?

Tags: c++

Чем отличается 0 от NULL? И как вообще называют такие имена как NULL? Какие ищё есть подобные этому примеру?

Comment: NULL це іменована константа -- \#define NULL 0  
прикладів можна навести багато-на С раніше не було логічного типу і його можна було відтворити із  
\#define bool int  
\#define true 1  
\#define false 0  
define це макрос, який повідомляє компілятору, що будь де(окрім тексту в лапках) треба одне замінити другим

Comment: Илья, я уважаю украинскую культуру и язык, но здесь принято, все-таки, писать по-русски. Если можешь, пиши по-русски, уважай других, поскольку не все на форуме владеют украинским языком.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NULL` — это всего лишь `#define` на `0`. С выходом [нового стандарта](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) рекомендуется использовать [`nullptr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf).

Comment: а какие ищё есть #define ?

Comment: Ещё есть любые define - их можно самому объявлять.

Answer (score 5):

Ещё можно создать свой аналог nullptr:

```
class null
{
    null() {}
    void operator&() const;
public:
    template<class T> operator T*() const {return 0;}
    static null _inst;
}
const &null=null::_inst;
class null null::_inst;
```

Comment: А какова практическая ценность подобных конструкций ? 

Обсуждение на конференциях по теоретическим основам семантики языков программирования и написание диссертаций ?

Comment: NULL не всегда соответствует nullptr. Например, можно написать int n=NULL, но нельзя написать n=nullptr или, используя мой null n=null. Если есть перегруженная функция  

    void func(int x);
    void func(void* ptr);

человек может захотеть вызвать вариант с void*, передав нулевой указатель, но если он использует NULL, то вызовет int-вариант. nullptr и null дадут ожидаемый результат. Если nullptr не поддерживается, лучше использовать этот null.

Comment: Ещё null запрещает ненужные операции. Его можно обрезать так:

    struct null
    {
        template<class T> operator T*() const {return 0;}
    } const null;

Comment: Ну так для чего это? 

Чтобы обучаемый еще меньше понимал, что на самом деле происходит в компьютере?

Comment: Причём здесь сам компьютер? Проблемы NULL - это проблемы языка, а не компьютера. null или nullptr исправляют некоторые недочёты языка.

Comment: Сам компьютер, естественно, ни при чем. Проблема именно в языке, который отодвигает программиста все дальше от компьютера. Результаты (требование программ к ресурсам) все мы видим.

Comment: Всегда за что-то нужно платить и так уж получилось, что за скорость написания программ мы платим растущими требованиями к производительности машин. Языки здесь совсем не виноватые :)

Comment: Мой код выше подставляемый. Скомпилируется так же, как если бы я поставил 0. Потерь в производительности не будет. А уж использовать это или нет решать программисту.
 Добавлено:  
Не могу добавить новый комментарий. Отвечу здесь:  
 Например, этот код могут использовать люди, переводящие по каким-либо причинам код с компилятора, поддерживающего nullptr на тот, который его не поддерживает. Он максимально идентичен тому, который появился в новом стандарте. Если заменить всё это на NULL, то вызов перегрузок функций может измениться - появятся баги.

Comment: Так **зачем нормальному программисту** использовать этот код ?

Хотел продолжить (уже с @Котик_...) но лимит выбрал.

На мой взгляд **nullptr** ни с выравниванием, ни с порядком байт и т.п., да наверное ни с чем динамическим не увязывается. Просто я балдею, когда язык раздувают непонятно кому нужными вещами.

Comment: @avp Ну примерно с той же целью, зачем **нормальные программисты** используют *статические ассерты*. Я, например, за то, чтобы переносить часть проверок соответствия на компилятор, нежели потом отлавливать их в рантайме. Тем более, что сработавщий статический ассерт лучше, чем неизвестные креши в продакшене из-за того, что, например, структура *оказалась выровнена не так, как ты ожидал.*

С `nullptr` та же история.

Comment: @avp Ну, не буду особо спорить. Тут просто дело в том, что кресты - это обобщение над простым `C`, соответственно, чтобы получить совместимость кодовой базы, многие вещи решались костылями, которые будут работать и там, и там. *А дальше для костылей начинают придумывать новые костыли, чтобы язык соответствовал каким-то более прогрессивным понятиям, типа, *"О, строгая типизация NULL!"*, давайте-ка это запилим. А т.к `#define NULL` уже есть, то давайте обзовем его `nullptr` и включим в новый стандарт.


Короче, стандартный путь для несовершенного языка, который развивался на протяжении 20 лет.

Comment: @avp Чувствую, я тут сейчас тоже за лимит выйду :)